# Закэшировать данные на несколько секунд

Tags: кэширование, php

Кто что использует для кэширования данных в php?

Периодически возникает задача закэшировать данные на несколько секунд.

Comment: Для небольшого периода времени, я использую *memcached*

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы.
Стратегия кеширования в приложении http://habrahabr.ru/post/168725/

Answer (score 2):

Вообще было бы не плохо знать, какие данные и для чего. От типа задачи решение может сильно отличаться.

Есть несколько способов:

- Простой кеш в файлах на жестком диске, очень часто этого достаточно для простых задач
- Использовать memcached
- Использовать redis, довольно мощный инструмент, можно хранить в памяти различные структуры данных, либо же просто текст, смотря какая цель. Но нужно предварительно настроить, чтобы не писал данные на жесткий диск. Можно устанавливать expiration.

Answer (score 0):

`memcached`, файлы либо бд. Больше нечего в принципе. Я лично не испытываю нагрузки на БД и храню там ибо контроль за этими кэшами, с моей точки зрения намного удобнее чем с файлами.

Comment: @Manitikyl, кэш - это временное хранилище, БД - постоянное. Они до некоторой степени взаимозаменяемы, но это всегда ведет к геморрою из-за замены ложки лопатой. Ну и кэш в файлах хранить совсем некомильфо.

Answer (score 0):

[@biohazardo](/users/22408/biohazardo) уже упомянул два варианта, которые в первую очередь приходят в голову – memcache и redis.  Есть ещё вариант кэширования в памяти: [APC](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.apc.php).

```
$bar = 'BAR';
apc_store('foo', $bar);
var_dump( apc_fetch('foo'));
```